# Rspec does not load the objects through has_and_belongs_to_many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, rspec

I have this in my model:

```
class Instance < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_and_belongs_to_many :owners, :class_name => 'User'
```

and this:

```
 class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :instances
```

and I have this migration:

```
 class CreateInstancesUsersJoinTable < ActiveRecord::Migration
     def up
       create_table :instances_users, :id=>false do |t|
         t.string :instance_id
         t.string :user_id
       end
     end

 def down
   drop_table :instances_users
  end
end
```

And in instance controller I have:

```
   @instance.owners << owner
```

but the tests says that owner is not into owners array. But when I say:

```
  p @instace.owners - before or after @instance.owners << owner
```

the test passes. Does anyone know why this happens?

Answer (score 0):

In User model you should write

```
has_and_belongs_to_many  :instances
```

instead of

```
  has_many :instances
```

Comment: Thanks for answering but this didn't decide the problem